# Git Bash - Segmentation fault

Tags: git, github, versionamento, windows-10

Olá, eu estou com um problema bem chato no programa do GIT. Quando eu abro o GITBash na pasta desejada e entro com qualquer comando, eles simplesmente dá o erro "Segmentation fault".

Eu dei uma pesquisada na internet antes de vir aqui, porém não encontrei nada a respeito do GIT. 
A única informação que eu encontrei é que esse erro está relacionado com a memória RAM.

[image: Print do Erro]

Minhas informações básicas do PC:

Sistema: Windows 10 Pro x64 (Preview Insider Build 14251)
Ram: 8gb
Programa com problema: https://git-scm.com/
Credenciais SSH e repositórios configurados corretamente em pastas com permissões gerais.

Desde já eu agradeço a comunidade do Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: Parece um bug no programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, eu consegui contornar o problema revertendo a build 14251 para a build 11099 do Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview.

Se alguém tiver uma solução que funcione na build 14251 eu ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score -1):

Falha de segmentação (segmentation fault, também referido por segfault) é um erro que ocorre em programa quando este tenta acessar (para leitura ou escrita) um endereço na memória RAM que está reservado para outro programa (ou o próprio sistema operativo) ou que não existe.

Esse problema ocorre por dois motivos:

1º Ocorre por acessar um ponto da memória não autorizado para sua aplicação. (Desktop)
2º Acontece porque você não está em uma pasta de repositorio do git.

Você precisa carregar um ponto de repositório local para o Git funcionar adequadamente.